# How to access an index created by APM in Kibana’s custom visualization?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I need to access some custom labels sent from the front in the `Dashboard --> Custom Visualization` area, I'm trying to do the following code but I don't seem to get anything. In addition, I am getting a specific index from APM itself that has a specific date, the aim is to get all APM label logs.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": "Gráfico de Linhas com Propriedade 'testandoAPM'",

  "data": {
    "url": {
      "index": ".ds-traces-apm.rum-default-2023.11.20-000001",
      "body": { "_source": ["labels.workspaceStringfyData"] },
      "size": 1000
    },
    "format": {"property": "hits.hits"}
  },

  "mark": "text",

 "encoding": {
    "x": {
       "field": workspaceId,
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": {"title": "ID"} 
    },
    "y": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "count",
      "axis": {"title": "HI"}
    }
  }
}
```

I also noticed that if I do the filter through custom visualization, the custom property does not appear, but if I do the filter by creating a normal chart (without using custom) I can access it.

PS: My property is an array of objects, in this case I created a `JSON.stringfy` from the frontend for Elastic, I need to use it as an array to access the properties and assemble the graph.